# Check if a string is larger than 2 megabytes in php

Tags: php, string

How in **php** can I check if a string is larger than 2 MB? We need to truncate strings that are large before inserting them into MongoDB, since the MongoDB document limit is 16MB.

**UPDATE**

The string can indeed have non ascii characters, i.e. utf.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#72274

Comment: Why do you need to know the size of your string?

Comment: MongoDB maximum document size of 16MB.

Comment: Okay. MongoDB uses utf-8 by default, where characters can either 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes.

Comment: So is the following correct: `if (mb_strlen($string, 'utf-16') >  1024 * 1024 * 2) {}`

Comment: No, it will return to you the number of characters in your string provided the string is `utf-16` encoded.

Comment: Either way - what strings are you storing that can possible be several megabytes?

Comment: stdout output, it is happening.

Comment: Okay, in that case I would imagine the output to exist initially in form a file? If this file is already utf-8 encoded, examining it's file size should give you a clue on how many bytes the text consumes.

Alternatively, to be on the safe side, you set a 1 million character limit based on the assumption that the average character size in utf-8 will be two bytes or less, which is a very reasonable assumption to make, unless your text is mainly made up of Asian glyphs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
<?php 
  if (mb_strlen($string, '8bit') >  1024 * 1024 * 2) {
    echo "larger that 2 MB";
  }

?>
```

Comment: You should add that you are using `'8bit'` to fool `mb_strlen` into reporting the number of bytes instead of the number of characters, which it was conceived for.

Comment: If checking a string that is going to get inserted in MongoDB should I use `utf-16` instead of `8bit`?

Comment: Also keep in mind that this technique may not be completely reliable, as the returned value will depend on the internal string representation of the PHP interpreter in question, when the programmer may actually be interested in the space consumption in it's future serialized state.

Comment: Justin, you should convert the string to "UTF-8" and then you can use mb_strlen with `8bit` to get the byte size of the string when it's UTF-8 encoded, which is what MongoDB uses from what I can tell.

Comment: Makes sense, so how about the following: `$str = utf8_encode($str); if (mb_strlen($str, '8bit') >  1024 * 1024 * 2) { $str = mb_substr($str, 0, 1024 * 1024 * 2, 'utf-8'); }`

Comment: `utf8_encode` is a broken function. Don't use it unless you are 100% certain that your incoming string has ISO-8859-1 (western european) encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

A string is a sequence of characters. The size of each character depends on what character it is and how it is encoded once saved to a file.

So a string itself has no size except the internal memory allocations for your PHP interpreter.

If performance is not an issue, you could write the string to a file with a character encoding of your choice and then examine the size of the written file.